# Variables not sent when pressing back button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, variables

I have a javascript that runs on a set of checkboxes to filter some items shown via PHP.

When someone filters the information and then clicks on an item, he is directed to that item's description. My issue is when that user clicks on the BACK button in the browser, since my filtering is already gone.

This happens because my script loads a .php but only inside a DIV (so I don't need to reload the whole page). This means my sent variables are just loaded at the DIV level and not at the URL level, so when they go to the description of a specific product and then go back, those variables are not there anymore and the filtering is gone.

Here is my JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
        var boxes = [];
        // You could save a little time and space by doing this:
        var name = this.name;
        // critical change on next line
        $("input[type='checkbox'][name='"+this.name+"']:checked").each(function() {
            boxes.push(this.value);
        });
        if (boxes.length) {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            // Change the name here as well
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?categ=<?php echo $category; ?>&'+this.name+'=' + boxes.join("+"),
            function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });

        } else {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?categ=<?php echo $category; ?>', function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Either open the item description in a new window, or (more elegantly) open the item description in a modal dialog (e.g. using [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)).